# LogCompaction - Kafka. How does it really work?

Tags: apache-kafka

I don't understand how logcompaction works.

I have create an configure a topic and consume from this topic

```
kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic COMPACTION10
kafka-topics --alter --zookeeper localhost:2181 --config min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01 --config cleanup.policy=compact --config segment.ms=100 --config delete.retention.ms=100 --config segment.bytes=1000 --topic  COMPACTION10
```

Later, I have created an scala program to insert (k,V) from 1 to 100 with the same K and V.

```
        val data_amount = 100
        val topic = "COMPACTION10"
        val kafkaConfiguration = new Properties
        kafkaConfiguration.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        kafkaConfiguration.put("key.serializer", Class.forName("org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"))
        kafkaConfiguration.put("value.serializer", Class.forName("org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"))

        val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](kafkaConfiguration)

        for (id <- 1 to data_amount){
            println( id )
            val record = new ProducerRecord(topic, id.toString, id.toString)
            producer.send(record)
        }
        producer.close()
```

After executing this, I got something like this:

```
1-1
2-2
3-3
4-4
5-5
6-6
7-7
8-8
9-9
10-10
11-11
12-12
13-13
14-14
15-15
16-16
17-17
18-18
19-19
20-20
21-21
22-22
23-23
24-24
25-25
26-26
27-27
57-57
58-58
59-59
60-60
61-61
62-62
63-63
64-64
65-65
66-66
67-67
68-68
Processed a total of 39 messages
```

Why do I get only 39 messages and don't 100 messages?? All they have a different key, so, it shouldn't have compaction.

If I send a new 100 values (1 to 100), I get about 50 messages with some new values.

Later, I have tried to send values with an empty value to do a delete compaction, but it's not possible to send a None or null value in the producer. If I send "" value, they are recognized like new values:

```
1-1
2-2
3-3
4-4
5-5
6-6
7-7
8-8
9-9
10-10
11-11
12-12
13-13
14-14
15-15
16-16
17-17
18-18
19-19
20-20
21-21
22-22
23-23
24-24
25-25
26-26
27-27
57-57
58-58
59-59
60-60
61-61
62-62
63-63
64-64
65-65
66-66
67-67
68-68
1-
2-
3-
4-
5-
6-
7-
8-
9-
10-
11-
12-
13-
14-
15-
16-
17-
18-
19-
20-
21-
22-
23-
24-
25-
26-
27-
28-
29-
30-
31-
32-
33-
34-
35-
36-
37-
Processed a total of 76 messages
```

How could I send empty values to get a delete compaction of some keys?

I have executed with these values with similar results:

I executed with these new parameters with similar results.

```
kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic COMPACTION11

kafka-topics --alter --zookeeper localhost:2181 --config min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01 --config cleanup.policy=compact --config segment.ms=1000 --config delete.retention.ms=10000 --config segment.bytes=1000 --topic  COMPACTION11
```

Comment: Please increase the amount of retention and test again .. I think its amount is very low and it quickly disappears.

Comment: But, why does it disappears records with no duplicates keys???

Comment: Please show the output of the `describe` command: `bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic  COMPACTION10`

Comment: Topic:COMPACTION10      PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:segment.bytes=1000,min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01,delete.retention.ms=100,segment.ms=100,cleanup.policy=compact
        Topic: COMPACTION10     Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0

Comment: I have increased those values with similar values, I have added in the main post the new values.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to send a null value in the producer

Comment: With my declaration val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](kafkaConfiguration) it's not possible to use val record = new ProducerRecord(topic, id, null). The only way it's to declare another producer as producer = new KafkaProducer[String, Null](kafkaConfiguration) and the it's possible to send it a null in the ProducerRecord, is that the way and to use delete log compaction?